# How to organize crud for tree state React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tree

Help me figure out how to work with tree states in React. I have initial data with an unknown nesting level.

```
const [tree, setTree] = useState([{
  id: 1,
  name: '1',
  children: [{
    id: 3,
    name: 3
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: 4,
    children: [{
      id: 5,
      name: 5
    }]
  }]
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 2
}])
```

I'm trying to do a deletion of items from the state. Editing elements, and adding children to the state.
To delete items, I wrote the following functionality.

```
const delete = (data, id) => {
  const updateData = data.reduce((acc, el) => {
    if (el.id !== id) {
      const updatedEl = { ...el};
      if (Array.isArray(updatedEl.children)) {
        updatedEl.children = recursiveDelete(updatedEl.children, id);
      }
      acc.push(updatedEl);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []]);
return updateData;
}


const handledRemoveItem = (id) => {
  setTree((prev) => recursiveDelete(prev, id));
};
```

I wrote a similar function for the update.

```
const update = (data, id) => {
    return data.reduce((acc, el) => {
        if (el.id === id) {
            acc.push({
                ...el,
                name:'test',
            });
        } else {
            acc.push({
                ...el,
                ...el.children ? { children: update(el.children, id) } : {}
            });
        }
        return acc;
    }, []);
}
```

Now in order to add children I need to change the update function.

```
        acc.push({
            ...el,
            children: [
                ...el.children || [],
                {
                    name: 'new-name',
                    id: 'new-id'
                },
            ],
        })
```

It seems to me that this is redundant code. And it can be simplified. Please advise how to work correctly with this data structure.I'm most interested in how to combine changing an element and adding children into one function

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use recursive function, for exemple delete:

```
  const deleteFunction = (nodeId) => {
  const removeNode = (nodes) => {
    return nodes.filter((node) => {
      if (node.id === nodeId) {
        return false;
      } else if (node.children) {
        node.children = removeNode(node.children);
      }
      return true;
    });
  };
  const updatedTree = [...tree];
  setTree(removeNode(updatedTree));
};
```

I don't know if this will work, you probably need to adjust this code to make it work...
try to do the same with the other functions

Comment: How is this different from my version? except for the fact that a filter will be used.

Comment: you asked how simplified and how to work properly with this data structure, recursive perfectly answers your request, recursion is a suitable choice for working with tree structures because it aligns with their hierarchical nature, simplifies logic, provides flexibility and scalability, enables code reusability, and supports problem decomposition. I hope it will help you